# Function for finding elements with <img> in them and then hiding it

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, hidden

I am trying to sue jquery to find all div elements in a certain class (.coverimages) that do NOT have an image inside of them. Once I have identified those elements WITHOUT an img. I want to hide that entire div. The code I have come up with will hide all the 's. Even the ones with an image in them. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('.coverimages').each(function() {
        if ($(".coverimages img").length == 0) {
            $(this).hide()
        }
});
```

I know I am probably missing something simple but I cannot figure out what!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the linked question's answer. In your case: `$(".coverimages:not(:has(img))").hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
$('.coverimages').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('img').length==0){
         $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: You *can* do it that way, but there are more concise options.

Comment: you also need to remove the quotes around `'this'`

Comment: Yes, yes... thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('.coverimages')` to all div with this 'coverimages' class and iterate array using `$.each()` to get required result.

**DEMO**

```js
var imgArr =document.querySelectorAll('.coverimages');

$.each(imgArr,(i,el)=>{
  if($(el).find('img').length==0){
    $(el).hide();
  }
});
```

```css
img{
height:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="coverimages">
<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/buttons/512/Icon_11-256.png"/>
</div>

<div class="coverimages">
<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/buttons/512/Icon_11-256.png"/>
</div>

<div class="coverimages">
<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/buttons/512/Icon_11-256.png"/>
</div>

<div class="coverimages">
<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/buttons/512/Icon_11-256.png"/>
</div>

<div class="coverimages">
don't have img tag
</div>
```